# Unit testing custom tableviewcell in xib file

Tags: swift, unit-testing, uitableview

I have a view controller class with a tableview in storyboard. In another separate xib file I have a custom table view cell with some attributes like image view, labels..etc in custom tableview cell class.

Now I have to write unit test case to test this custom cell and its attributes. I have tried the following,

```
import XCTest
@testable import Citizens_Bank

class InvestmentTableViewCellTests: XCTestCase {

    var newsVC: NewsViewController!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the  invocation of each test method in the class.

    }

   func testCustomViewContainsAView() {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: NewsDetailsTableViewCell.self)
    guard let _ = bundle.loadNibNamed("NewsDetailsTableViewCell", owner: nil)?.first as? UIView else {
        return XCTFail("CustomView nib did not contain a UIView")
     }
  }

  func testCustomCell() {
     let customCell: NewsDetailsTableViewCell = accountsVC.myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newsDetailsCell") as! NewsDetailsTableViewCell
    XCTAssertNotNil(customCell, "No Custom Cell Available")
  }
}
```

testCustomcell test case function is getting crashed with this error in console log "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". How can I test my custom tableview cell and its attributes? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let yourView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourView") as! yourView
```

then call

```
 let customCell = yourView.myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourView") as! NewsDetailsTableViewCell
```

Comment: Check by debug, which variable was nil?, are the table view in Nib file?